# Need help for non-renewable subscription in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to implement In app Purchase and i am new to this: 
I have to give free subscription for three days, after that i will sale day pass like $1 for one day. and after completion of that 1 day user will buy the next day pass.

so i studied a lot and found that i have to create non renewable in app purchase. (please suggest if i am wrong)

I have created an app where users can sign up.

Is it possible to provide the subscription according to my app users not according to  Apple ID (itunes purchase ID).

For example my app users are:

UserA
userB
userC

and i am purchasing with testuserA (itunes or apple Id).

so here can i purchase three time for these three users.

please suggest i am having fear of app rejection.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: What's the worst that can happen if Apple rejects your app?  They say no, you fix some things, and then try again?

Comment: Need to upload my app on app store asap already running beyond the schedule. So can't afford rejection.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer too. What I see is that the non-renewable subscription can be purchased multiple times from the same device. I do not see anything about the situation with the multiple users on the same device.

Comment: I implement Non-Renewable IAP by managing it to my application server. But today get rejection under Apple Guidelines 11.6 Stated "Content Subscription using IAP must last minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS Devices."

I manage the subscription on all iOS devices but for just 1 day subscription. :(

Comment: Can you model this as a Consumable product?